# How to return this XML-RPC response in an array using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to put together a WordPress plugin and I want to grab a list of all categories (of other WordPress blogs) via XML-RPC. I have the following code and it looks like it works so far:

```
function get_categories($rpcurl,$username,$password){   
    $rpcurl2 = $rpcurl."/xmlrpc.php";

    $params = array(0,$username,$password,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.getCategories',$params);
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    $res = xmlrpc_decode($results);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
```

If I use `$res` I get the following string as the response: `Array`

If I use `$results` then I get:

```
categoryId17 parentId0 descriptionTest categoryDescription categoryNameTest
htmlUrlhttp://test.yoursite.com/?cat=17 rssUrlhttp://test.yoursite.com/?feed=rss2&amp;cat=17
categoryId1 parentId0 descriptionUncategorized categoryDescription
categoryNameUncategorized htmlUrlhttp://test.yoursite.com/?cat=1
rssUrlhttp://test.yoursite.com/?feed=rss2&amp;cat=1
```

I need to pull out the names after `description` so `Uncategorized` and `Test` in this case.

It's my first time coding in PHP. I got these results by echoing them to the page, so not sure if they get changed in that process or not...

By the way I modified the above code from one that posts to a WordPress blog remotely so maybe I haven't set some of the options correctly?

With `var_dump($res)` I get:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(7) { ["categoryId"]=> string(2) "17" ["parentId"]=> string(1)
"0" ["description"]=> string(4) "Test" ["categoryDescription"]=> string(0) ""
["categoryName"]=> string(4) "Test" ["htmlUrl"]=> string(40)
"http://test.youreventwebsite.com/?cat=17" ["rssUrl"]=> string(54)
"http://test.youreventwebsite.com/?feed=rss2&cat=17" } [1]=> array(7) {
["categoryId"]=> string(1) "1" ["parentId"]=> string(1) "0" ["description"]=>
string(13) "Uncategorized" ["categoryDescription"]=> string(0) "" ["categoryName"]=>
string(13) "Uncategorized" ["htmlUrl"]=> string(39) "http://test.youreventwebsite.com/?cat=1"
["rssUrl"]=> string(53) "http://test.youreventwebsite.com/?feed=rss2&cat=1" } }
```

Comment: Is your response not suppose to be `XML` in `XML-RPC` ???

Comment: Sorry Baba, not sure what you mean...

Comment: what you get with var_dump($res)?

Comment: @AurimasLičkus I've updated my question above with the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate your array:

```
foreach($res as $item) {
   echo $item['description'] . $item['categoryName'] . $item['htmlUrl']; //etc...

}
```